# Firebase Firestore not showing documents created in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a new in using Cloud firestore.

1. My purpose is to save a data to Cloud firestore and retrieve the entire collection.
   I am doing the Get started with Cloud Firestore (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#optional_prototype_and_test_with).
   In the step **Add data**, i do not see the data in the Firebase console.
   In the console I do not see any errors.
2. I checked the internet connection: it worked.
   I also used no proxy.
   I checked service account.
   I set the rules as following:
   `service cloud.firestore {`
   `match /databases/{database}/documents {`  
   `match /{document=**} {` 
   `allow read, write: if true;`
   `}`
   `}`
   `}`

But I see nothing in data in cloud firestore.
Any helps? Thank you a lot!

3. The code to save and get data as following

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = admin.firestore();

async function quickstartAddData(db) {
  // [START firestore_setup_dataset_pt1]
  const docRef = db.collection("users").doc("alovelace");
  await docRef.set({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815,
  });
  // [END firestore_setup_dataset_pt1]

  // [START firestore_setup_dataset_pt2]
  const aTuringRef = db.collection("users").doc("aturing");
  await aTuringRef.set({
    first: "Alan",
    middle: "Mathison",
    last: "Turing",
    born: 1912,
  });
  // [END firestore_setup_dataset_pt2]
}

async function quickstartListen(db) {
  // [START firestore_setup_dataset_read]
  const snapshot = await db.collection("users").get();
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  });
  // [END firestore_setup_dataset_read]
}
```

Comment: You are not triggering your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the functions `quickstartAddData(db);` && `quickstartListen(db);` but you have not called them.

Add this at the bottom of your function.

```
quickstartAddData(db);
quickstartListen(db);
```